# php laravel sort array of items based on month name in month order

Tags: php, laravel, sorting, collections, eloquent

I have a result set like,

```
{"data_points":
[{
    "monthname": "Apr",
    "value": 62
},{
    "monthname": "Aug",
    "value": 1904.53
},{
    "monthname": "Feb",
    "value": 33.33
},{
    "monthname": "Jan",
    "value": 2033.33
},{
    "monthname": "Jul",
    "value": 90.83
},{
    "monthname": "Dec",
    "value": 2030
},{
    "monthname": "Mar",
    "value": 100
},{
    "monthname": "Sep",
    "value": 433.33
},{
    "monthname": "May",
    "value": 5670.93
},{
    "monthname": "Jun",
    "value": 40.4
},{
    "monthname": "Oct",
    "value": 0
},{
    "monthname": "Nov",
    "value": 31
}]}
```

and I want to sort items by *data_points.monthname* using month order, like

```
{"data_points": [{"monthname":"Jan", "value": 2033.33}, {"monthname": "Feb", "value":33.33} ........]}
```

Comment: Are you sure, it is an array or a collection?

Comment: Yes, the result set is a collection

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

In order to sort the Collection using Laravel Supplied method following code can be used

```
$collection->sort(function ($a, $b) {
            $monthA = date_parse($a['monthname']);
            $monthB = date_parse($b['monthname']);

            return $monthA["month"] - $monthB["month"];
        });
```

Laravel Documentation mentions that if your Sorting is complex you can use a callback to [Sort](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-sort)

Below is the code if you want to sort in Vanilla PHP.

```
$data = '{"data_points": [{ "monthname": "Apr", "value": 62 },{ "monthname": "Aug", "value": 1904.53 },{ "monthname": "Feb", "value": 33.33 },{ "monthname": "Jan", "value": 2033.33 },{ "monthname": "Jul", "value": 90.83 },{ "monthname": "Dec", "value": 2030 },{ "monthname": "Mar", "value": 100 },{ "monthname": "Sep", "value": 433.33 },{ "monthname": "May", "value": 5670.93 },{ "monthname": "Jun", "value": 40.4 },{ "monthname": "Oct", "value": 0 },{ "monthname": "Nov", "value": 31 }]}';
$decoded =  json_decode($data, true);

usort($decoded['data_points'], "compare_months");

$data = json_encode( $decoded );

print_r($data);

function compare_months($a, $b) {
    $monthA = date_parse($a['monthname']);
    $monthB = date_parse($b['monthname']);

    return $monthA["month"] - $monthB["month"];
}
```

Bascially you need to Convert the months to a numerical value. Then sort on the basis of that.

Here is the working Demo on [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/pi4I6)

Comment: I'm expecting solution with laravel eloquent collection

Comment: You have to use PHP in Laravel to reformat the array.

Comment: No, we are dealing with laravel collections, not expecting overhead of conversion to array.

Comment: @ShivarajRH I have updated the answer to sort by Laravel Collections.

Comment: I feel using date_parse() little slow, is there any optimal way?

Comment: @ShivarajRH no there is no other way. If you want to sort by Month you need to convert them to numerical values.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a collection, why you are not using [sortBy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-sortby) collection method.

example

```
$sorted = $collection->sortBy('month');
```

I don't think it will work for month, but in that case, you can just traverse through the collection using `map` or `each` method and save as another collection or array.

Comment: No, this will sort by month name in alphabetical order but not on default month order!

Comment: @ShivarajRH then traverse through the collection and save in another collection or array or better when you are retrieving from database, use sort by there.

Comment: Sorry bro, It's an Eloquent collection its huge data, laravel person will understand the format which I shared.

Comment: @ShivarajRH then why you are trying to sort after retrieving and not when you are retrieving from database?

Answer (score 0):

with the help of answers, I got an optimal solution,

```
$sort_collect = $result->sortBy(function ($item, $i) { 
    return ( Carbon::parse($item->monthname)->format("m") );
});
return $sort_collect;
```

returns the desired order, 
thank you both @ascsoftw, Prafulla Kumar Sahu